# Socket.io - sending both user and message data

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have been following the Getting Started page on Socket.io and have completed the main task. However, now I am trying to implement a new feature so it sends the name of the user back with the message. Whilst this sends back the message fine, I am not sure how to implement it so it also sends back the data for the user. I understand I can copy the code below and edit it to the user-specific things, but then what?

Emit the user as normal:

```
socket.emit('chat message', $('#u').val());
```

Then, retrieve that on the server:

```
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
```

Then, display that information on the page:

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li class="mesg">').text(msg));
  });
```

Comment: Emit it as JSON object and then parse it, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jonathan commented,  just send it as an Object.

Note that socketio automatically serializes/deserializes for you, so you don't need the extra JSON.stringify steps.

Here's an example from my game code I'm using right now:

```
//client.js
io.emit('waypoint', { x: players.me.targetX, y: players.me.targetY });

//server.js
socket.on('waypoint', function (msg) {
   console.log(msg.x, msg.y);
});
```

So in your case, something like this,

```
//client.js
    io.emit('chat message', { msg: $('#u').val(),
                              userColor: 'green',
                              moreData:{ isAwesome:true, favoritePie:'apple'} });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I've understood your question correctly, but I think all you'd need to do is emit a JSON object as your message, and then parse the response on the other side, like so:

```
var obj = {message: $('#u').val(), user: "User"};
socket.emit('chat message', JSON.stringify(obj));

socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });

socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    var message = JSON.parse(msg).message; //$('#u').val()
    var user = JSON.parse(msg).user;       //"User"
    $('#messages').append($('<li class="mesg">').text(message));
  });
```